# Outlook COMException

Tags: outlook-object-model

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
Could any body please help me out by finding the error. I have created a windows application using OUtlook COM with Office 2010. I have a timer which after a specific interval takes the data from sql server database and then add up into the sql server database. But my applicatio is giving this exception when i am creating the object of Outlook.Application class.

Answer (score 3):

This might be due to privileges of the process. I usually run Visual studio as administrator, but if outlook is not previously started as also admin, the COM call will fail.

Simple solution. Run both as administrator or run both as normal privilege level.